# Rscript.exe is getting hang after the execution of R script from file using mxnet package

Tags: r, rscript, mxnet

`Rscript.exe` is getting hang without closing console after the execution of *R* script using `mxnet` package.Can anyone suggest to close the console after the execution

[image: Screenshot is available here]

Comment: Please include the script that is being used.

Comment: There is no issue with the script. The output from the script is as expected, but I want to execute the script from C#. So I am using System.Diagnostics.process to execute RScript.exe with script file(sample.r) as a command line argument.It is executing the script as expected and also I am getting proper output too. But the console is not closing after completing the execution of the script, also I am not able to execute any more command on the same window and it shows as shown in a screenshot .The console is able to close only by manually.

Answer (score 0):

This seems related to this bug:
http://wpkg-users.wpkg.narkive.com/TiZdkHmj/rscript-hanging-when-run-from-wpkg

> Adding STDOUT redirection to NUL is an option too. In case Rscript.exe
>   prints a lot of output on the console (>4kB) it will "block". This is
>   a known issue with Microsoft WSH.

Try to reduce the verbosity of your script.